# Как сделать вывод ошибок при регистрации в placeholder

Tags: php, html

Вопрос в заголовке: вот я хочу сделать регистрацию. И планирую выводить ошибки в placeholder. То есть,при входе на страницу регистрации, сначала в placeholder'е будет записано что-то вроде "Введите пароль". Я создал массив,куда будут заноситься ошибки.Как сделать так,чтобы данные из этого массива выводились в placeholder?

Comment: Например, можно слать AJAX и на JS переписывать его либо воспользоваться куками

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин А можете пожалуйста поподробнее,как это куками сделать?

Comment: Записываешь на PHP в $_COOKIES что-то, а на фронте делаешь условия в нужных местах и проверяешь с выводом из $_COOKIES

Comment: Ладно,буду думать, спасибо за ответ